# select box validation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

i am new to Codeigniter and I have some trouble in select box validation. I want default select value at beginning.

```
<select name="schooGroups[]">
<option value="0">Select User Group</option>
<option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

how can i make it required field in form and display error message on select of zero "0" value.

Comment: There is no need to create an array for select box eg `schooGroups[]`, suffixing `[]` creates an array unless otherwise needed or multiple select box is used instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will have the entry marked as "selected" as...selected by default. You want a multi-select dropdown, right?

```
<select name="schoolGroups[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select User Group</option>
<option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

As for validation, you might want to build your own validation rule:

Your controller's method:

```
//...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('schoolGroups','School groups','required|callback_check_default');
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'You need to select something other than the default');

//...
```

The add this other method:

```
function check_default($array)
{
  foreach($array as $element)
  {
    if($element == '0')
    { 
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
 return TRUE;
}
```

If you just want a single select (no ability to multiselect then) it's even easier:

html:

```
<select name="schoolGroups">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select User Group</option>
<option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Method with validation:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('schoolGroups','School groups','required|callback_check_default');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'You need to select something other than the default');
```

Callback:

```
function check_default($post_string)
{
  return $post_string == '0' ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: thanks Damien for prompt response. i just add it and get the error message as "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name" instead of my one :( m i missing some thing?.

Comment: its done i used call back function name as field name in set_message. $this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'You need to select something other than the default');

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my mistake, I added that part in a haste!I now corrected it, for future reference. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of doing this is by setting the value of the default option to empty! Then you can use a simple form_validation rule like for a text field:

```
<select name="schoolGroups">
  <option value="">Select User Group</option>
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('schoolGroups','School groups','required');
```

Comment: 100% agree but sometimes your list is populated from an array and have no choice but having first option 0

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

**THE VIEW**

```
<select name="schoolGroups[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select User Group</option>
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('schoolGroups','School groups','callback_check_default');
```

**CALLBACK**

```
function select_validate()
{
    $choice = $this->input->post("schoolGroups");
    if(is_null($choice))
    {
        $choice = array();
    }
    $schoolGroups = implode(',', $choice);

    if($schoolGroups != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'You need to select a least one element');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I ensure a numeric validation for each element in case a man-in-the middle attack gives a malicious input?